# Allow chart overflow over plot area

Tags: highcharts, overflow

Is there anyway to allow highcharts overflow over plotarea?

[image: Allow highcharts to paint outside Y Axis]

Fiddle [Bubbles clipped](http://jsfiddle.net/carolo/L5sbLxzv/1/)

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {

"chart":{"type":"bubble"},
"plotOptions":{"bubble":{"minSize":9,"maxSize":30}},

"xAxis":{"min":0},

"series":[
   {"name":"Acero", "data":[[604807,9091,19235608]],"color":"#ff0000"},
   {"name":"Xleado","data":[[189725,281,2006799]],"color":"#33A1DE"},       
     {"name":"Aleado","data":[[40261840,85391,156180]],"color":"#104E8B"}
         ]    
});
```

Comment: Please share the code that generates the situation from the image. Markers  can exceed the plot area and still be visible as you can see in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/2xqvvx8b/

Comment: Sure @Kamil Kulig, http://jsfiddle.net/carolo/L5sbLxzv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG `clip-path` attribute is responsible for hiding some parts of the bubbles.

It can be easily disabled via CSS:

```
.highcharts-series {
  clip-path: none;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/h5yymapp/